# store tabbar tabs order in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar based app where i add controllers to the app like this :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
self.tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

// FirstViewController
SoccerViewController *fvc=[storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SoccerViewController"];
fvc.navigationItem.title =  @"Fodbold";
fvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"fodbold.png"];

//SecondViewController
HaandballViewController *svc=[storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HaandballViewController"];
svc.title=@"Håndbold";
svc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"handball.png"];

//ThirdViewController
FootballViewController *tvc= [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FootBallViewController"];
tvc.title=@"Amr. Fodbold";
tvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"nfl.png"];

//ForthViewController
BasketballViewController *fovc=[storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BasketBallViewController"];
fovc.title=@"Basketball";
fovc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"basketball.png"];

//FifthViewController
HockeyViewController *ftvc=[storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HockeyViewController"];
ftvc.title=@"Ishockey";
ftvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icehockey.png"];



[API sharedInstance].allViewCont = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:fvc,svc,tvc,fovc,ftvc,  nil];


self.tabbar.viewControllers=  [API sharedInstance].allViewCont;

[self.view addSubview:self.tabbar.view];

 // NSLog(@"%@", [API sharedInstance].allViewCont);

 //[self performSelector:@selector(hideSports) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

self.tabbar.delegate = self;
```

Now the saving works  and i close the app and reopen  i get this :

```
"<HaandballViewController: 0x7fdd9a589bd0>",
"<SoccerViewController: 0x7fdd9a58ac40>",
"<FootballViewController: 0x7fdd9a593180>",
"<BasketballViewController: 0x7fdd9a594350>",
"<HockeyViewController: 0x7fdd9a58efe0>"
```

but i can't set the sorted taps like this :

```
- (void)setTabOrderIfSaved {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"sortetTabs"];
NSMutableArray *savedOrder = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSMutableArray *orderedTabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
  NSLog(@"Test af gem array %@",savedOrder);
if (savedOrder!=nil && [savedOrder count] > 0 ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [savedOrder count]; i++){
        for (UIViewController *aController in self.tabbar.viewControllers) {
            if ([aController.title isEqualToString:[savedOrder objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                [orderedTabs addObject:aController];
            }
        }
    }
    for (UIViewController *aController in self.tabbar.viewControllers) {
        int loaded=0;
        for (UIViewController *bController in orderedTabs) {
            if ([aController.title isEqualToString:bController.title]) {
                loaded=1; 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        if (loaded==0) { 
            [orderedTabs addObject:aController]; 
        } 
    } 

    self.tabbar.viewControllers = orderedTabs;
}
```

i fixet this .......

Comment: You shouldn't be adding the tab bar controller's view as a subview without making the tab bar controller a child view controller -- even then, I'm not sure you should be doing it. The tab bar controller probably should be the window's root view controller, or you could present it modally from another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is definitely overkill to store a user preference. You should be using `NSUserDefaults`. Simply store an array of strings describing your controllers (you can use those lovely unreadable abbreviations you came up with).

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:
  @[@"fvc", @"svc", @"tvc", @"fovc", @"ftvc"] forKey:@"TabsOrder"];
```

So to get your mutable array from the defaults:

```
NSMutableArray *tabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TabsOrder"]];
```

To store it once the editing has finished:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tabs forKey:@"TabsOrder"];
```

Comment: as i sayed i store them in a NaMutable array and in a tabelview in settings the user can reach and drop the cell to make the order that they want and i tried adding to NSuserdefault but not one of the ways I've seen worked. and ( as long at i know the abbreviations  )

Comment: This is how it is done. I will expand my answer to explain how you can use the static array in user defaults to populate your mutable array. [_It would help if you could try writing intelligible English_.]